# Data in a grid view wont show until I refresh the page c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, redirect

I have a button that sends a session variable and redirects to another page where the page should read the variable and display data based off of the string of the session variable, and it works but it wont show unless I refresh the page. Heres the button click:

```
protected void btnJoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button lb = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
    getText1 = row.Cells[1].Text;
    Session["showName"] = getText1;
    Response.Redirect("ViewLeague.aspx");
}
```

and heres the page load for the ViewLeage.aspx:

```
string SQLName = "SELECT teamname, draftedPlayer1, player1FP, draftedPlayer2, player2FP, draftedPlayer3, player3FP, draftedPlayer4, player4FP, totalFP FROM Drafted_Table WHERE LeagueName = '" + Name2 + " '";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (this.Session["showName"] != null)
        {
            Name2 = (String)this.Session["showName"];
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Heres where the data gets added to the gridview

```
private void GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // get the connection

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source= tyler-pc\\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=true; Database=CODFANTASY2"))

    {

        // write the sql statement to execute

        string sql = SQLName;

        // instantiate the command object to fire

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))

        {

            // get the adapter object and attach the command object to it

            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

            {

                // fire Fill method to fetch the data and fill into DataTable

                ad.Fill(table);

            }

        }

    }

    // specify the data source for the GridView

    ViewLeagueTable.DataSource = table;

    // bind the data now

    ViewLeagueTable.DataBind();


}
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: First, you're using the `Name2` value in your SQL query before you've actually assigned anything to it.  (Note: The way you use it also presents a SQL Injection vulnerability.)  So the clause will always be `WHERE LeagueName = ''`.  Second, the `Page_Load` event in `ViewLeague.aspx` doesn't actually display any data to the user.  If some other event is doing that, then it's not going to display anything until that event is triggered.

Comment: ill add the part where the data gets added

Comment: Solved awesome thanks, I needed to move the sql string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems I'm seeing here...

**First**, when you perform a redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("ViewLeague.aspx");
```

The only events on the target page (`ViewLeague.aspx`) which will be invoked are the init/load/etc. events.  A button click may have led to the redirect, but no button on the target page was clicked so no other such handler is going to be used.

Thus, in order for anything to show in the grid when that page loads, it needs to happen in the `Page_Load` handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    GetData();
}
```

**Second**, you're using the value before you assign anything to it:

```
string SQLName = "SELECT teamname, draftedPlayer1, player1FP, draftedPlayer2, player2FP, draftedPlayer3, player3FP, draftedPlayer4, player4FP, totalFP FROM Drafted_Table WHERE LeagueName = '" + Name2 + " '";

// Later...
Name2 = (String)this.Session["showName"];
```

If `Name2` was empty when you used it, then that SQL clause will be:

```
WHERE LeagueName = ''
```

So if there are no records with an empty `LeagueName` value, then there will be no data to show.  You need to set the value in the query after you obtain the value.  (**And** you should do so with a parameter, to avoid SQL injection.)

```
string SQLName = "SELECT teamname, draftedPlayer1, player1FP, draftedPlayer2, player2FP, draftedPlayer3, player3FP, draftedPlayer4, player4FP, totalFP FROM Drafted_Table WHERE LeagueName = @Name";

// Later...
Name2 = (String)this.Session["showName"];

// Later...
var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLName);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDataType.VarChar, 25).Value = Name2;
// etc.
```

(I had to guess on the column type and size, adjust accordingly.)